# Django-Autocomplete-Light v3 widget doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

So I'm doing everything as the tutorial says, I have successfully registered the autocomplete view and when I go to the right url I can see the queryset displaying as it should in json format. However I cannot get the form widget to work.

If my form looks like this:

```
class ProductsImportForm(ModelForm):
    brand = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Brands.objects.all(), label=_('Brand'))
    filename = forms.FileField(label=_('Filename'))
    fileType = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FileType.objects.all(), label=_('File type'))

    class Meta:
        model = ProductsImport
        fields = ['brand', 'filename']
        widgets = {
            'brand': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='brand_autocomplete')
        }
```

The select field on my page looks the same as it has before, without any fancy autocompletes.

Now when I delete the widget part from Meta and move it here:

```
brand = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Brands.objects.all(), label=_('Brand'), widget = autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='brand_autocomplete'))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Reverse for 'brand_autocomplete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

How can I fix it? I really need to have this autocomplete field on my page, as I'm browsing though hundreds of entries.

Comment: How did you include the autocomplete view url ?

Comment: @jpic 'url(r'^brand_autocomplete/$', BrandAutocomplete.as_view(), name='brand_autocomplete')'

Comment: Could you post the urls.py script that's referred to by settings.ROOT_URLCONF ?

Comment: ROOT_URLCONF = 'b2b.urls', my url is in the products.urls, which is included in the b2b.urls, so I guess it should work.

However after moving it to the main file I can see the correct queryset under the corresponding url, but now, my form doesn't display any options to choose. Oh well :)

Comment: how is it included ? could you post your b2b.urls ? what do you mean the form doesn't display any option ? is the JS properly loaded ? is there any error in the js console ?

Comment: Yes, js is loaded as other elements on the page using js are correctly displayed. Form doesn't display any option as in after clicking the select field there is nothing to choose from, emptiness. Js console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: also in my b2b.urls the is this: url(r'^products/', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),

and in products.urls this: url(r'^brand_autocomplete/$', BrandAutocomplete.as_view(), name='brand_autocomplete'),

It doesn't matter if i place the url in b2b or products, the address works and displays the correct querysets

Comment: Could you perhaps close this topic and create a new one ? I just can't help with little details like that in a pair of comments ... If JS is loaded correctly, does select2 shows ? If so, what happens in the console when you click it ? Is there any network request ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a DAL issue, but a Django issue. It can't reverse the url with name "brand_autocomplete", because it wasn't registered in Django.

See [Django's documentation on the URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/) for details.